# Assign click to dynamically created data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have created javascript in which data is fetched for dropped element and are created. The data is fetched from database using json encoding. I have assigned id to the elements but the click event for every element is not working. only the last elements `id` is obtained and clicked is performed on that `id`.

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var i,j=0;
var x1,x2,y1,y2;
var sf=pf;
sf=Math.round(sf);
var tmp;
var y=null;
var idiv=[];
var fty=ft;
var fd=fid;
var fetch=data;
var x = null;
var count=fetch['count'];
var i=count+1;
//document.write(count);
var rai=[];
//rai[0]='hello';
//document.write(rai[0]);
var ww=[];
var hh=[];
var xx=[];
var yy=[];
var room=[];
var roomt=[];
for(j=0;j<=count;j++)
{

    rai[j]=fetch['room_id'+j];
    //document.write(rai[j]);
    ww[j]=fetch['width'+j];
    //document.write(ww[j]);
    hh[j]=fetch['height'+j];
    xx[j]=fetch['x'+j];
    yy[j]=fetch['y'+j];
    room[j]=fetch['room'+j];
    roomt[j]=fetch['roomt'+j];
    //document.write(room[j]);
   // alert("data"+rai+"  "+ww+" "+hh+" "+xx+" "+yy);
    idiv[j]=document.createElement('img')
    $('#droppable').append(idiv[j]);
    idiv[j].style.position="absolute";
    idiv[j].style.left=(xx[j]*sf)+'px';
    idiv[j].style.top=(yy[j]*sf)+'px'; 
    idiv[j].style.width=(ww[j]*sf)+'px';
    idiv[j].style.height=(hh[j]*sf)+'px';
    idiv[j].style.border=1+'px';
    idiv[j].id=room[j];
    //y=idiv[j].attr('idd',rai[j]);
        if(roomt[j]=='garden')
    {
        idiv[j].src="images/download.jpg";
    }
    else
    { 
        idiv[j].src="images/ac.png"
    }
    $(idiv[j]).draggable();
    //alert(y);
    //y=idiv[j].id;
//  alert(y);

//document.write("data"+rai[j]+"  "+(ww[j]*sf)+" "+(hh[j]*sf)+" "+(xx[j]*sf)+" "+(yy[j]*sf) + room[j]);
}
//$(this).bind("click",'idiv',function(){
//          alert("hello"+idiv.id);
//window.location.href="tables.php?room_id="+y;
//  });
});
```

can anyone give idea how to bind click on each fetched element.

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document, if you have duplicate ones replace them by class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty this : add class to the element created and write a click event handler for all element having that class. See below

Add below html in Loop where you are creating `idiv[j]` -

```
idiv[j].className = "clickable";
```

Now write a click event handler using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...... your code start here
    ......
    //loop
    for(j=0;j<=count;j++)
   { 
    ...
    ...
   }
   //loop ends
   ... more code
   ....your code end here
    $(document).on("click",".clickable", function(){
         alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

**NOTE**:  Don't use `bind` because it is deprecated now after jQuery version 1.5

Comment: classname gets assigned, and where should I write on click I tried both inside and outside for loop but nothing is working.any other idea?

Comment: I used bind instead of on,its working but its not getting the id of element,its getting undefined.

Comment: write click event handler outside loop at the end but inside of `$(document).ready...` block.  See my updated answer

Comment: I wrote it outside the loop, but its not getting the id.

Comment: Sorry it worked now.I had done some mistake had written className as classname. thanks for your help

Comment: happy to help you :)